# JSON Parsing issue: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."

Tags: json, type-mismatch

I'm facing an error with parisng a JSON.
I can see that I have type mismatch however I'm not sure how to fix it:

typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

```
var dataModel = [Model]()
```

This is my model:

```
import Foundation

struct Model: Codable {
    let basepath: String
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Codable {
    let title: String
    let abstract: String
    let thumbnail: String
}
```

And this is my root view controller within which I'm parsing JSON.

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let hostingView = UIView()
    let cellID = "cell"
    
    var dataModel = [Country]()
    
    let tableView: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.rowHeight = 100
        table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return table
    }()
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.showSpinner(on: hostingView)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureView()
        configureConstraints()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
        performRequest()
    }
    
    private func configureView(){
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        title = "Game Of Thrones"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
    
    private func configureConstraints(){
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    private func performRequest(){
        let url = "https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/api/v1/Articles/Top?expand=1&category=Articles&limit=75"
        let urlString = URL(string: url)
        guard urlString != nil else {return}
        print(String("URL: \(urlString)"))
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: urlString!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let decodedData = try decoder.decode([Country].self, from: data!)
                    self.dataModel = decodedData
                    print(self.dataModel)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.removeSpinner()
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print(error)
                        self.performRequestError()
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
    
    private func performRequestError(){
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Cannot load data", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if dataModel.count > 0 {
//            return dataModel[0].items.count
        }
        return 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "title"
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Show your JSON. Or, paste it into https://app.quicktype.io to have the corresponding structs generated for you.

Comment: I found a solution - I had to change let decodedData = try decoder.decode([Country].self, from: data!)
                    self.dataModel = decodedData --> to --> let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Country.self, from: data!)
                    self.dataModel = [decodedData] :) - as always small mistakes....